# Where can I find a heightmap of South Africa?

Tags: data-request, africa

I've been looking for a heightmap of South Africa for a while but I can't seem to find the kind I need anywhere. It needs to be a Grayscale Raster of high quality.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTopography supports downloading heightmaps (and other data) from several sources.

https://portal.opentopography.org/datasets

Here's the current sources available for South Africa:

1      Copernicus Global Digital Elevation Models
2      NASADEM Global Digital Elevation Model
3      Global Bathymetry and Topography at 15 Arc Sec: SRTM15+ V2.1
4      Global Multi-Resolution Topography (GMRT) Data Synthesis
5      ALOS World 3D - 30m
6      Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) Global

You may need some dataprocessing to convert the raw data to Grayscale Raster.